# FluentMigrator rollback not working

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-migrator

I see the related question already there. [FluentMigrator Failed Migrations Don't Rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2124795/3835843) and [Rollback to a specfic Migration in FluentMigrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36856251/3835843). But unfortunately i can't solve my rollback issue with this solution. I am using [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) to versioning database.

My migration code :

```
using FluentMigrator;

namespace WebCruiter.Candidate.DBMigration.Migrations.R2016_6
{
    [Migration(20160908000908, "USERSTORY")]
    public class Migration20160908000908 : AutoReversingMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Create.Column("TestUrl").OnTable("JobApplication").AsString(500).Nullable();
        }
    }
}
```

And my attempt to rollback this version(`20160908000908`) from command line:

```
migrate.exe -c "server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Candidate;Integrated Security=True" -db sqlserver2014 -a ".\..\..\..\WebCruiter.Candidate.DBMigration\bin\Debug\FluentMigrator.dll" -t rollback:20160908000908
```

Without rollback column **TestUrl** from **JobApplication** it shows :

[image]

Can anybody help me out where i made a mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to give the runner the number of the migration before the one you want to rollback to. So say you have migrations 1, 2, and 3. And you want to rollback 3, you would give the runner *2*

What you are giving the runner at the moment is not that, give it the migration before '20160908000908'.

This is basically what was written in [Rollback to a specfic Migration in FluentMigrator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37735034/6427909), You write the number of the migration you want as your last one, not the number of migration you want to rollback to.